# overload the + operator to add 2 polynomials

Tags: c++

I'm trying to add two polynomials stored in a 2D array with the first rows store the coefficients and the second row store the degree.

I created a overloading + function but here I use 2D allocated memory array and it crashes when the function is called.

**Update: it runs now but the results are some big negative numbers

FYI, I have a copy constructor and an overloading = operator

```
// overload +
Polynomial Polynomial::operator+(const Polynomial &right)
{

    maxExp = right.maxExp;
    poly = new int *[maxExp];
    for (int i=0; i < maxExp; i++)
        *(poly + i) = new int[2]; 

    Polynomial temp = *this;

    for (int i=0; i < maxExp; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            temp.poly[i][j] = poly[i][j] + right.poly[i][j];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: What's that `delete poly[]` supposed to do? It seems out of place.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` and avoid much of the memory-management headache?

Comment: @NPE sorry I have not learnt about Vector yet so I have no idea how to use it

Comment: "It crashes" ... you should be more specific. What debugging have you tried? Where does it crash? What is the input you give to make it crash? What is the state of the local variables at the crash?... help us help you.

Comment: It will be easier to learn `std::vector<double>` than to learn memory management.  You should eventually do both.

Comment: That shouldn't crash unless your copy constructor and/or assignment operator are wrong.

Comment: @Herious whether this now fixed?

Comment: yeah i fixed it another way @Toms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems, but the most glaring one is that the very first line:

```
delete [] poly;
```

destroys one of the summands (the `x` in `x + y`). It also leaks memory, but at this point this is secondary.

**edit:** I notice that you've edited the `delete[]` out of your question. This doesn't fix the problem, but makes it worse: you're still overwriting the summand, but now are leaking even more memory.

Comment: yeah that was a mistake, it was intended for the assignment. But without that line the program still crashes when this function is called

Comment: @Herious: Well, you've removed the `delete[]` but you're still overwriting the summand.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point, I remove that line in the assignment `=` also, the program runs now but the results are some ugly negative numbers, what are they?

Answer (score 2):

just start with += and copy operators and make the + operator form that.

Comment: sorry I don't get it, what do you mean start with +=

Comment: [c++ overloading guidelines](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html)